# Error 91 / 438 when working with Set and .Find Range

Tags: excel, vba, object, set, named-ranges

This Program is Supposed to Open A whole lot of Workbooks, the One at the top of the list (filename1, AKA Plan) is a place to upload many different cells of data, every other opened workbook is functionally the same. The file opening present no issues.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim Plan, Leg As Workbook
Dim FileChosen As Integer
Dim CUILT As String
Dim CuiltRange As Range

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

FileChosen = fd.Show

fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
fd.Filters.Clear
fd.Filters.Add "Plan Excel", "*.xlsx"
fd.Filters.Add "Leg Excel, "*.xlsm"
fd2.FilterIndex = 1

If FileChosen <> -1 Then

MsgBox "The Operation has been stopped"

Else

FileName1 = fd2.SelectedItems(1)
Workbooks.Open (FileName1)
Set Plan = ActiveWorkbook

For i = 2 To fd2.SelectedItems.Count
Workbooks.Open fd2.SelectedItems(i)
Set Leg = ActiveWorkbook

CUILT = Leg.Sheets(1).Range("I19").Value

Plan.Worksheets(1).Activate
```

Now comes the part of the code that's giving me trouble, with the help of some other post I was able to navigate through the finicky nature of the find:Variable function, but right after I was able to sort that error, the "Found Range Variable = Range" now just doesn't want to cooperate. It gives me error 91, it's as if CuiltRow is not actually saving any value in the previous Set operation, even when I try to MsgBox after "Set" to figure it out, if just tells me its not defined, Every other out I've tried has ended in

> error 438 "object doesn't support property or method".

```
Set CuiltRow = Plan.Sheets(1).Range("C16:C421").Find(CUILT, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
CuiltRow.Offset(0, 5).Range("A1").Value = Leg.Sheets(1).Range("D14").Value
```

The Set CuiltRow wont work without the Set, and I know the set is the one causing the 91? Honestly, im at a loss, Any help Would be Appreciated!

```
Next i
'Else
'End If

MsgBox "Operation has been completed"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End If
End Sub
```

**I Just want to use the range CuiltRow returns as a reference waypoint to set many offsets, but with my poor syntax in "Range(offset) = Range" function VBA believes I'm trying to set a Value into a Range Object, how can I express it differently so its clear?**

Comment: You need to test if the `Find` succeeded: `If Not CuiltRow Is Nothing Then`... and only then proceed to do `CuiltRow.Offset(0, 5).Range("A1").Value ...`

Comment: There was a conditional if, I had to took it down cause just after it there need to be a "Next i" and apparently, having an if before the Next i gives a compile error "Next without for".